# LocationBox Distance Matrix API

Tags: python, matrix, location, distance, mapbox

I want to create a distance matrix I made it by using googlemap APi with this code

```
url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins={0}&destinations={1}&mode=driving&language=en-EN&sensor=false".format(str(orig_coord),str(dest_coord))
result= simplejson.load(urllib.urlopen(url))
driving_time = result['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['distance']['value']
```

Now, I want to make same matrix by using LocationBox. But I dont know how to put distances data to an array. Here is output:

```
{u'status': 0, u'distances': [{u'topoint': {u'latitude': 40.984818, u'type': 0, u'name': u'POINTB', u'longitude': 29.083635}, u'distance': 12865, u'frompoint': {u'latitude': 41.1, u'type': 0, u'name': u'POINTA', u'longitude': 29.1}}, {u'topoint': {u'latitude': 40.948784, u'type': 0, u'name': u'POINTC', u'longitude': 29.170496}, u'distance': 17809, u'frompoint': {u'latitude': 41.1, u'type': 0, u'name': u'POINTA', u'longitude': 29.1}}, {u'topoint': {u'latitude': 40.948784, u'type': 0, u'name': u'POINTC', u'longitude': 29.170496}, u'distance': 8335, u'frompoint': {u'latitude': 40.984818, u'type': 0, u'name': u'POINTB', u'longitude': 29.083635}}], u'transactionid': u'LBS_98961306'}
```

How can I get Distance data from this output?

Comment: By LocationBox, do you mean Mapbox?

Comment: No. LocationBox is another applicaton like mapbox and Google Maps

Comment: Okay - you'll want to tag this with `locationbox` instead of `mapbox`, then.

Comment: Yes, but i could not tag it. In order to add new tag  i should have at least 1500 reputation :(